# how to print data using the condition in python based on mysql result data

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration

i have a mysql sample data resulting like below table

```
main_cat| sub_cat | number | org_id
Career  | school  | 5      | A
Career  | college | 3      | A
Career  | higher  | 4      | A 
Job     | Blr     | 6      | A
Job     | Hyd     | 11     | A
Job     | Chennai | 12     | A 
Career  | school  | 15     | B
Career  | college | 30     | B
Career  | higher  | 5      | B 
Job     | Blr     | 5      | B
Career  | college | 8      | C
Job     | Chennai | 4      | C
```

I want to print top 2 `main_cat` for every organization. For every top 2 `main_cat`, I want to print top 2 `sub_cat` for every organization. So every organization should have 4 or less records with top 2 `main_cat` and top 2 `sub_cat` for each `main_cat`

Please help me.

Comment: How is this table defined? Is it a result from `cursor.execute()` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For grouping python provides [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), which groups **sorted** input by a given key function.

In this case the input needs to be sorted first by `org_id`, then by `main_cat` then by `number` in descending order, e.g. if your data as a list looks like this:

```
data = [
 ['Career', 'school', 5, 'A'],
 ['Career', 'college', 3, 'A'],
 ['Career', 'higher', 4, 'A'],
 ['Job', 'Blr', 6, 'A'],
 ['Job', 'Hyd', 11, 'A'],
 ['Job', 'Chennai', 12, 'A'],
 ['Career', 'school', 15, 'B'],
 ['Career', 'college', 30, 'B'],
 ['Career', 'higher', 5, 'B'],
 ['Job', 'Blr', 5, 'B'],
 ['Career', 'college', 8, 'C'],
 ['Job', 'Chennai', 4, 'C']
]
```

then you'd sort it like this:

```
data.sort(key = lambda x: (x[3], x[0], -x[2]))
```

or by altering your sql statement to include `ORDER BY main_cat, sub_cat, number DESC`, then you'll aready get it in the right order from the database.

Now you can use `groupby` to group, and `islice` to limit the number of results per grouped category:

```
from itertools import groupby, islice
from operator import itemgetter

# already sorted data
data = [
 ['Career', 'school', 5, 'A'],
 ['Career', 'higher', 4, 'A'],
 ['Career', 'college', 3, 'A'],
 ['Job', 'Chennai', 12, 'A'],
 ['Job', 'Hyd', 11, 'A'],
 ['Job', 'Blr', 6, 'A'],
 ['Career', 'college', 30, 'B'],
 ['Career', 'school', 15, 'B'],
 ['Career', 'higher', 5, 'B'],
 ['Job', 'Blr', 5, 'B'],
 ['Career', 'college', 8, 'C'],
 ['Job', 'Chennai', 4, 'C']
]

data.sort(key = lambda x: (x[3], x[0], -x[2]))

for org, by_org in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(3)):
    print("org:", org)
    for cat, by_cat in islice(groupby(by_org, key=itemgetter(0)), 2):
        print("  cat:", cat)
        for subcat, by_subcat in islice(groupby(by_cat, key=itemgetter(1)), 2):
            print("    subcat:", subcat, " = ", list(by_subcat))
```

Output:

```
org: A
  cat: Career
    subcat: school  =  [['Career', 'school', 5, 'A']]
    subcat: higher  =  [['Career', 'higher', 4, 'A']]
  cat: Job
    subcat: Chennai  =  [['Job', 'Chennai', 12, 'A']]
    subcat: Hyd  =  [['Job', 'Hyd', 11, 'A']]
org: B
  cat: Career
    subcat: college  =  [['Career', 'college', 30, 'B']]
    subcat: school  =  [['Career', 'school', 15, 'B']]
  cat: Job
    subcat: Blr  =  [['Job', 'Blr', 5, 'B']]
org: C
  cat: Career
    subcat: college  =  [['Career', 'college', 8, 'C']]
  cat: Job
    subcat: Chennai  =  [['Job', 'Chennai', 4, 'C']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to process your query into dataframe with [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_sql(connection,query)
result = df.groupby(['org_id', 'main_cat', 'sub_cat'])['number'].head(2)
```

Variable `connection` is your connection to db and `query` is your `SELECT` string.